# Careers won't let me list Reykjavik, Iceland as location

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, location

If I type this into the Location box

> Iceland

It works, but if I type (with or without the comma)

> Reykjavik, Iceland

It turns it to

> Reykjavik, Reykjavik Iceland

UPDATE: I found out why this is.

[Check out this query](http://bit.ly/2tMs5o)

Careers is just listing the Region and City. But the issue is larger than that, since they can't just ignore region if it's == to city, or [this query](http://bit.ly/1DSTTx) would be wrong.

Comment: Clearly, they're biased against Vikings. Maybe they're afraid you'll pillage all the jobs.

Comment: nice detective work!

Comment: Or, status-by-american-capitalist-pig

Answer (score 11):

Same silly nonsense for Zürich:

> Zurich, Canton of Zurich Switzerland

It sounds harsh, but I find this to be a very *"provincial"* approach to city/something/country categorization that my fellow Americans tend to suffer from *en masse*.  I'm too scared to see what is says for such locations as Singapore and Dubai.

The form did not insist upon 5-digit postal codes, so I guess that is a plus.

Comment: Provincial? Looks Cantonal to me... *ducks*

Comment: Ah, the translation there would be *Klugscheisse*...

Comment: @Shog9: I was with you up until the part about waterfowl.

Comment: Same problem with Lisbon, Portugal, it turns into Lisbon, Lisbon Portugal

Comment: "Kosice, Kosicky Slovakia" feels _very_ wrong to me. I would not publish a profile, that features this error so prominently under my name. What about adding at least comma between the region and country? I preffer my exact words "Kosice, Slovakia". If you want to display a region, why not use a map instead?

Comment: @Stu: would we end up in an infinite recursion if I pointed out to you that there is an `r` missing at the end of the word you used? :)