# Problem with location field on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Careers wont let me list Reykjavik, Iceland as location](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24962/careers-wont-let-me-list-reykjavik-iceland-as-location)

When I type in

> Berlin, Germany

in the location field, the form automatically changes it to

> Berlin, Berlin Germany

Same with the field "Where do you want to work?"

Comment: Maybe it's a New York state of mind.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24962/careers-wont-let-me-list-reykjavik-iceland-as-location

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is in the form:

```
City, Region Country
```

Berlin is both a city and the name of the [federal state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_of_Germany) Berlin (city) is in. So for somewhere else in Germany it might be:

```
Koeln, Nord-Rhine Westphalia Germany
```

It's just confusing because it's Berlin twice so it doesn't strike me as a bug per se.

Comment: I don't think it is, check out my link in the comments above. Reykjavik isn't a region of Reykjavik.

Comment: it's `North Rhine-Westphalia`

Comment: @Ólafur: You're right. Wolfram|Alpha returns Reykjavik,Hofudhborgarsvaedhi,Iceland (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reykjavik). Hofudhborgarsvaedhi? Say no more...

Comment: I did get it somewhat wrong. In German it's Nordrhein-Westfalen. In English it's North-Rhine Westphalia.

Comment: It's a bug because it assumes all locations should be formatted/displayed/stored strictly as "City, Region Country".

Comment: In Europe when you have a duplicate city name, you add a local detail; e.g. Frankfurt am Main (am Main = at the river Main) vs Frankfurt an der Oder (at the river Oder). The US way is more generic, but not widely used in Europe. For smaller towns, you just accept the confusion.

Comment: Sounds like a case of YAGNI to me, people know best how to say where they're from. Just change it to a free text field.

Comment: @Edward Tanguay: Don't change it to a free text field. Entries here will be used for matching. Otherwise e.g. a candidate willing to work in `Köln` might not be found by an employer who offers a position in `Cologne, North Rhine-Westphalia Germany` (that's what Köln is changed into automatically). Having a common a database here is a good thing. Let them switch the API for location lookup if it#s not appropriate but don't use free text field. Anyway: Change it for what reason? Cause it doesn't look nice???

Comment: In North Rhine-Westphalia born and raised, at the Reichstag where I spent most of my days...