# Where in the world is "Moscow, Moskva Russia"?

Tags: bug, jobs, geography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does careers location field change Jyväskylä to Jyvaskyla?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla)

When I type "Moscow, Russia" in careers.stackoverflow.com, it corrects me to "Moscow, Moskva Russia". What's the point?

Moskva is Russian reading of the Russian capital which is known as Moscow in English speaking world. It is a dedicated federal subject, not the part of Moscow Oblast. Also there is no other moscows in Russia. So "Moscow, Russia" is enough. Same goes for "St. Petersburg, Russia". Same, I think, is for all federal submissive cities around the world.

Answer (score 7):

Careers uses Yahoo Geo DB (via YQL) to get geographical names. That would be the address for your request or question. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla) too for more information.