# The Netherlands Antilles do not exist anymore

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, location

Today I noticed to my astonishment that my location was changed from *Willemstad, Curaçao* to *Willemstad, Netherlands Antilles* without any intervention. I've changed it back on SO, but I've kept it as is here on MSO. When I changed it on SO, it incorrectly asked me if I meant for it to be Netherlands Antilles:

---

[image]

---

The Netherlands Antilles have been [dissolved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolution_of_the_Netherlands_Antilles) since 10-10-10. The country **does not** exist anymore. The geographical locations that comprised it are now Curaçao (CW), St. Maarten (SX) and BES— Bonaire, St. Eustatius and Saba (BQ).

Please update your country database. An up-to-date ISO 3166 table can be found [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.htm). Its legend says, for Netherlands Antilles:

> Code element deleted from ISO 3166-1; **stop using ASAP**

Comment: I think you should report this on yahoo api site.

Comment: For another example of this, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla

Comment: It's not actually St. Maartan, according to ISO-3166-1 Newsletter VI-8 it's Sint Maartan (Dutch Part) :-)

Comment: The title sounds like you're complaining about the dissolution of the country, rather than the form supplying outdated information!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I think that was a trick to draw attention, well, I ignored it.

Comment: @Andrew: In real, it is the other way round. Gert: How is it possible that you posted a comment in an ignored question?

Comment: @Chichiray - hahah, that's humour!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the response we get from the [Yahoo PlaceFinder API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/), so from *our* side it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), however it is certainly info that needs updating in their API.

To resolve this you'll need to ask on the [Yahoo PlaceFinder forums](http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showforum=124&endsession=1).

Comment: OK, I've asked it http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showtopic=9021 Thank you.