# Obsolete country name on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, location

The Careers site has "Serbia and Montenegro" instead of separate entries for "Serbia" and "Montenegro".

[Serbia and Montenegro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbia_and_Montenegro) has been broken up since 2006. Since then, [Serbia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbia) and [Montenegro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montenegro) are separate countries, and as such it should be possible to select either of them.

Comment: I would say that both variants of countries ( && and ||) should be presented

Comment: This country field is not used for historical purposes, but for the actual place where the person is living, so I really don't see the point of having the name of the country that no longer exists.

Comment: As has been documented multiple times, Careers uses Yahoo's API for place names. The bug is with Yahoo, not Careers.

Comment: @Shinhan I got that. But i thinked about backward compability: what would be with peoples that already have "Serbia and Montenegro" now in Careers? We have to force them to change it? Cause I don't see there a possibility to make a choice for them automatically.

Comment: @mmyers sorry, first time here. Yahoo is big, any idea where I can submit this bug to them?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90034/the-netherlands-antilles-do-not-exist-anymore; looks like the place to go is http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showforum=124&endsession=1.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the report!

Shinhan's problem is with our Country Dropdown list on the profile page.  We were filling it with countries that should've matched an ISO Spec.  The spec that governs country codes is [ISO 3166](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166) which has multiple revisions.  The revision we seemed to be working off of had "Serbia and Montenegro - CS" marked as an acceptable country in a transitional state since September 2006.  Followers of the spec would be were allowed to use it for 5 years since the start of the transitional period which would have ended September 2011.  So our dropdown has been out of spec for 6 months.  BOO US and our non spec following ways.

This is now fixed.

Comment: You were actually just looking for a place to use this as a good reason to explain why the list was never correctly updated, weren't you? :)

Comment: Now I can select "Serbia", but my city is renamed to "Zubotica". Any ideas why? [Subotica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subotica)

Comment: @Shinhan maybe for the reason outlined in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/29548/131713)?