# South Sudan becomes "Augusta, GA, USA" in list of places willing to relocate to

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

In my list of places I am willing to relocate to, I list "Sudan" because that is closest to "South Sudan". When I try to list "South Sudan", Careers automatically rephrases that as "Augusta, GA", which is not quite the same.

I think this should be fixed.

Comment: Augusta is such a nice place, especially in April...

Comment: Potentially similar to [Obsolete country name on careers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125810/obsolete-country-name-on-careers)

Comment: Speaking personally, I'd rather be in Augusta, GA than South Sudan. Fewer horrible insects for one thing.

Comment: True enough. But South Sudan is much more exciting. Although I am beginning to want to visit Augusta some day!

Comment: Is this still an issue? I'm not using Careers, but on SE sites [I get the right suggestion today](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2nT1y.png). But: I never tried earlier. And Careers might be using a different mechanism.

Comment: And what does using `The Republic of South Sudan` get you?

Comment: "Republic of South Sudan" becomes "Sudan".

Comment: @David, as Yahoo! *does* know about the newish South Sudan (at least, when [limiting searches to country](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select+woeid%2C+name%2C+country%2C+placeTypeName%2C+admin1%2C+admin2%2C+admin3++from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22South+Sudan%22), like in the Meta profiles), I just want to confirm: are you sure this is by design?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect it is linked to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90034/the-netherlands-antilles-do-not-exist-anymore) about the break-up of the Netherlands Antilles. The [Yahoo Placefinder API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/) took a very long time to work out that 3 new countries existed.

As South Sudan is "so" new - only 9 months - the Yahoo Placefinder API probably hasn't had a chance to catch up yet, *ahem*.

If it's the same you'll have to yell at Yahoo as this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for SO.

Comment: Confirmed: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=South+Sudan There appears to be a Sudan Rd in Augusta.

Comment: Nice, @David. On the other hand: it has a "quality" rate of 72, whereas other searches show much lower values such as 10. Maybe results with high values can be ignored?

Comment: Odd that on this very site, [things are fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2nT1y.png) (today). I don't use Careers though, so it might be a different system, @David.

Comment: Ah, here on Meta it's explicitly asking for a country (and Yahoo actually does know about South Sudan), while relocation on Careers might be looking for cities or counties. For the country in one's profile here on Meta: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select+woeid%2C+name%2C+country%2C+placeTypeName%2C+admin1%2C+admin2%2C+admin3++from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22South+Sudan%22