# Careers 2.0 county/area issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I know this isn't a huge issue but on Careers 2.0 when I enter my area as "Ayrshire" or "North Ayrshire" it gets automatically changed to "Strathclyde".  Now as far as I am aware and according to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strathclyde), Strathclyde hasn't been used for the regional area since 1996.  As I say I know this isn't a huge issue but I don't want it to seem like I don't know my own address to potential employers.

UPDATE:
I didn't realise it is based on the postcode not what you type in,  to reproduce type in a postcode from one of the Scottish regions then click create PDF and the area shown in the top right will be the old region name.  Reported it to the yahoo people [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/PlaceFinder-Enhancement-Requests/Scottish-regional-areas-out-of-date/1336385135969-209e3334-3557-4e33-874d-b702885489d7).

UPDATE 2:
It is all of the area codes of Scotland which are affected, I did a quick test with google maps with a few post codes, here is what the area names should be for a few areas and then what careers puts as the address:

```
Post Code   Google's result                    Career's result
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DD1 5PE  = Dundee, Dundee City DD1 5PE,        Tayside
KA12 8EE = Irvine, North Ayrshire KA12 8EE,    Strathclyde
AB10 7NJ = Aberdeen, Aberdeen City AB10 7NJ,   Grampian
AB12 4TQ = Portlethen, Aberdeenshire AB12 4TQ, Grampian
```

Comment: The Careers site makes use of Yahoo's Geo API, so this is a bug you'll need to file with them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Netherlands Antilles do not exist anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90034/the-netherlands-antilles-do-not-exist-anymore)

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed – we had a cached value for Strathclyde. Try it again?

Comment: It's not fixed, see my update2, I don't think you understand the problem.  The region names are 16 years out of date so unless you cached them in 1996 I don't think it's a cache issue.

Comment: @Bunnit yep, looks like you're right.  Yahoo is returning "Strathclyde" for "KA12 8EE" http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22ka12%208ee%22

Answer (score 2):

This is yet another bug in Yahoo's API.  See here: [developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22KA12%208EE%22](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22KA12%208EE%22)