# Location is automatically updated with reverse look-up, which is wrong

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, location

When I enter Trstená, Slovakia into the Location box, it's updated to Trsztena (which is Hungarian name for the town, but it's not used here!). Please make it possible to override the automatic reverse look-up, or at least update your database (use OpenStreetMap maybe?).

Comment: SE is using [Yahoo! PlaceFinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/), so any issues should be reported to them individually. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90034/the-netherlands-antilles-do-not-exist-anymore

Comment: Why not use OpenStreetMap Nominatim?

Comment: Also, why not add a possibility to override what the service gives to you?