# Profile editor suggests butchered location

Tags: bug, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does careers location field change Jyväskylä to Jyvaskyla?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla)

When I edit my profile and set location to `São Paulo, Brazil`, it asks if I meant `Sao Paulo, Brazil` without the tilde:

[image]

No, I didn't. This probably isn't too big a deal except for pedantic people like me, but it still bothers me on principle. Why is it suggesting an incorrect spelling over a correct one?