# Careers: Customizable Location

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I was experimenting with Careers.StackOverflow and tried inserting my location (Manchester), which it changed to

> Manchester, England United Kingdom

Which for someone in the UK is very strange as it is only really standard to put one of them (England or United Kingdom).
I understand it uses YQL and it is formatted in the form of

> City, Region Country

However, would it be possible to have the option of what parts appear on the public view? Maybe just as a subcatogary to `Location` in the `publish cv` section, with three checkboxes...

- City
- Region
- Country

To allow a nicer cv presentation for people who do want to include their location on the public view.

Comment: This has been discussed before here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24962/careers-wont-let-me-list-reykjavik-iceland-as-location

Comment: It is a feature request and a proposed solution to the problem rather than something that just leads to a status-bydesign tag