# Location field spells city name incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, spelling, location

I happen to live in [Haifa, Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haifa). When I type this into Careers, the result becomes

```
Hefa, H'efa Israel
```

Why is that? Consulting the Wiki entry above, Hefa (or H'efa - would that be the Klingon spelling?) is not a pronunciation of the city name in any of the locally spoken languages. A search for Haifa returns 6,950,000 results, while a search for Hefa returns 297,000, so the intarwebs tend to agree with Wikipedia on the spelling as well.

Please fix that. Or maybe, while you iron out such errors in location names, you could consider allowing freeform entry in that particular field and make text replacement a suggestion, not a mandate - since I  prefer leaving the field empty to having my CV show this mistake.

Comment: Dupe?  Have a look at this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla

Comment: Hefa is not an accepted spelling in English, unlike Jyvaskyla. It's simply an error in Yahoo's DB, and there probably are many others.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, having it as a freeform entry is much better.

5 years from now many countries and cities will have died, and many new ones will have formed.. And it would be difficult to keep up.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look at

- [Why does careers location field change Jyväskylä to Jyvaskyla?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla)
- [Careers won't let me list Reykjavik, Iceland as location](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24962/careers-wont-let-me-list-reykjavik-iceland-as-location)

This is entirely dependent on what the [Yahoo Geolocation API](http://www.ygeoblog.com/) returns.

Comment: From other posts, I've understood that you're relying on that API, and it's the right way given rolling your own geolocation would be insane. But some results (such as this one) are subpar. Are you planning to address this in any way / relax the autorewriting rule?

Comment: ++ on the solution of making a 'suggestion' not an 'absolution'. Yahoo can't even get State side cities right.