# Careers adds a space in the middle of my towns name

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location field spells city name incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36638/location-field-spells-city-name-incorrectly)

I'm not sure why but the javascript seems determined to make what should be 'DeWitt' 'De Witt' on [my careers page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/xenoterracide). I live here, I know how it's spelled, there's no space. It shouldn't be correcting me. If it thinks I'm wrong let it suggest spellings but not override mine.