# Careers won't let me list Pécs, Hungary as location

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, location

TL;DR it's like letting you specify `Texas`, but not `Houston`. Since Houston is big enough to specify, employers will assume you don't live there if you didn't name it

In the Location field, `Pécs, Baranya, Hungary` gets corrected to `Baranya, Hungary`.

On the other hand, `Pécs, Hungary` gets corrected to `Mecek Sabolc, Pécs Hungary`.

The following things are wrong with that:

- It's spelled Mecsekszabolcs, and it doesn't exist since 1947, in fact this is the first time I've heard this form
- It's called Szabolcsfalu since then, and is now a part of Pécs
- Pécs is a city, not a county
- Pécs is the fifth largest Hungarian city, a UNESCO World Heritage Site, and won the title European Capital of Culture for 2010, and is therefore more notable (and correct) than Baranya

`Mecek Sabolc` actually looks like the Serbian spelling. Google has 6500 hits, all mentions presumably originate from the same database, every location mentioned is in fact in Pécs, and most hits are twitter-facebook-type spam.

For reference, here's the full list of possible search terms for this geographic region (in the looking-for-programmers context):

```
Pécs, Baranya, Hungary
Pecs, Baranya, Hungary
Pécs, Hungary
Pecs, Hungary
Hungary
```

In light of this and the other problems people are having with Location, would it be feasible to have a checkbox saying `[ ] Don't correct me, I know where I live`?

Comment: Browse these questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/location -- there are a whole bunch of similar issues.

Comment: I did my research, this is not a duplicate. Basically the database has a nonexistent village associated to my city, and this promotes the city into a county.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36638/location-field-spells-city-name-incorrectly/36646#36646

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla

Comment: I have resigned myself to the fact that as I don't live in the US, I don't get a proper sounding location. I get: "Manchester, England United Kingdom". Not any where near as bad as your issue but still strange non the less.