# careers.stackoverflow is not allowing me to put my real City name

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location field spells city name incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36638/location-field-spells-city-name-incorrectly)

When I enter my city name while editing my careers profile, it changes my city name from `Pula` to `Pluj` after saving the profile. [`Pula`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pula) is a real city in Croatia.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rz6v.jpg]

Comment: you forgot to put border on image @gnat, dont worry i have already done that editing for you

Comment: I'm not sure what `gnat` is but thanks for the pic. :)

Comment: He is master of editing, you can find his name in many question/answer for editing @AndrejM.

Comment: What's that big round ring looking thing in the middle of your city?

Comment: It's an amphitheatre: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pula_Arena

Comment: @Lucifer in cases like this, quote trick is not that important because image background differs from that of the question

Comment: @gnat, opps, a lot more to learn from your regarding editing, will keep this thing in mind for future, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Yahoo thinks the name of the town is "Pluj"

[http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22Pula%20Croatia%22](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22Pula%20Croatia%22)

```
<place xmlns="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng"
    xml:lang="en-US" yahoo:uri="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/849901">
    <woeid>849901</woeid>
    <placeTypeName code="7">Town</placeTypeName>
    <name>Pluj</name>
    <country code="HR" type="Country">Croatia</country>
    <admin1 code="" type="County">Istarska</admin1>
    <admin2 code="" type="District">Pula</admin2>
    <admin3/>
    <locality1 type="Town">Pluj</locality1>        
    <areaRank>2</areaRank>
    <popRank>9</popRank>
</place>
```

There's not a lot we can do in this case.  You can try reporting the bug to Yahoo but they haven't been terribly responsive to these requests in the past.

Comment: You could just not mess with the city name? I'll just delete my account, thanks.